# Как вытащить имя рандомной картинки, отосланной пользователю в телеграмм боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Я учитель математики и пытаюсь написать тг бота для детей. Суть - несколько папок с файлами по заданиям (1,2,3..), при вводе номера задания отсылается картинка с рандомным соответствующим заданием, подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать имя того файла, который выпал, чтобы прописать ответы на задания и дети могли делать проверку? Заранее спасибо

```
from random import random
import telebot
from telebot import types
import random
import os

bot = telebot.TeleBot('')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    mess = f'Привет, {message.from_user.first_name}'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, mess, parse_mode='html')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_user_text(message):
    if message.text == "Задание 1":
        photo = open('1/' + random.choice(os.listdir('1')), 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)


t.polling(non_stop=True)
```

Comment: Здесь, хорошим тоном считается добавлять код не картинками а текстом, для этого используйте ``` cod ```. Тройной апостроф  должен быть на отдельных строках, код посередине

Comment: И уточните как конкретно располагаются файлы и папки.

Comment: Также не нужно указывать `parse_mode` если вы не используете никакую разметку.

Comment: Я исправил как мог, папка пока одна с заданием 1 C:\Users\Фроловы\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\1 , в ней файлы формата 1_4_3 (первая цифра номер задания, вторая прототип, третья номер задания прототипе)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не совсем понял как вы будете использовать такое название файла, но думаю разберетесь.
Делал со своего темплейта, игнорируйте мой токен.
Если есть вопросы задавайте

```
import os
import random
import time

from telebot import TeleBot, types

import config

bot = TeleBot(config.BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message: types.Message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Приветствую, {message.from_user.first_name}\n"
                                      f"Начать тест?")

# тут я делаю фильтр на ввод от юзера
# он будет срабатывать только если юзер напишет да или Да
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda msg: msg.text.lower() == "да")
def start_test(message: types.Message):
    # лезем в папку с тестами
    tree = os.walk("tests")
    test = None
    for directory, folders, files in tree:
        # необязательно, но мне пришлось так как при каждом перезапуске
        # бота этот сид не менялся
        random.seed(time.time().real)
        # выбираем рандомно название файла
        test = random.choice(files)
        break
    # открываем файл
    with open(os.path.join("tests", test)) as f:
        data = f.read()
    
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Вот твое задание\n{data}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)
```

Comment: В целом я бы использовал инлайн кнопки для получения фидбека от юзера, а не требовал его писать да

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ. Кнопку может добавлю, когда разберусь, идея у меня возникла пару часов назад только, это мой первый бот. Мне бы хотелось понять как добавить проверку задания, я думал, что , зная название файла, через огромный блок if / elif смогу добавить проверку. Чтобы пользователь вводил ответ и ему давался ответ Верно / неверно. То есть при рандоме имя файла привязывать к какой-нибудь переменной и далее пошли условия.

Comment: Для такого я бы рекомендовал перейти на aiogram значительно проще реализовать то что вы хотите.

Comment: А если нет, то можете просто сделать глобальный словарь где ключ будет айди юзера `message.from_user.id` а значение... Ну к примеру название файла, которое у вас лежит в `test`